# Confused about ColdFusion syntax (quotes and pound signs)

Tags: coldfusion

I'm confused about two different styles of syntax and want to know which one is considered as a good programming practise with ColdFusion.

In the first example, the `returnvariable` is not using double quotes. Nor is the CFSET variable:

```
<cfinvoke component="#UserObj#" method="MyMethod" 
       username="#MyUserName#" 
       Returnvariable= ReturnVar><!--- No double quotes --->

<!--- No double quotes & no pound signs --->
<cfset session.userright = ReturnVar>
```

In the second example, the code *is* using double quotes for the `Returnvariable` and for the CFSET. The first one is set as ReturnVar while the other one is using double quotes and pound signs `"#RetunsVar#"`

```
<cfinvoke component="#UserObj#" method="MyMethod" 
       username="#MyUserName#" 
       Returnvariable= "ReturnVar"><!--- using double quotes  --->

<!--- using double quotes & pound signs --->
<cfset session.userright = "#ReturnVar#">
```

It looks like I can use both styles and either will work?

Comment: http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/2/10/when.do.i.use.pound.signs

Comment: Here is some good information about common CF mistakes. http://coryfail.com/common-cf-mistakes/

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for good programming practice you should start by not using `cfinvoke`

If you're on ColdFusion 9 or higher you can use the follow syntax.

```
<cfset userObj = new UserObj()>
<cfset returnVar = userObj.MyMethod(MyUserName)>
<cfset session.userright = returnVar>
```

Or you can simplify even more by eliminating the extra setting of a variable

```
<cfset userObj = new UserObj()>
<cfset session.userright = userObj.MyMethod(MyUserName)>
```

There is no need to use `"` or `#` when setting a variable. I would also recommend not using any type of variable named `retVar` or `returnVar` or `somethingThatDoesn'tExplainWhatItIs`

Comment: Thank you! I'm using CF10 and actually I'm calling my component using the following: <CFSET LogObj = createObject("component", "cfcomponents.mylog").init('#Trim(Form.username)#','#Trim(Form.Password)#')> Then I I used cfinvoke. So this is no good for CF 9 and above? I thought I have to use init()

Comment: if you use new you can pass your init arguments into the parenthesis  `<cfset lobObj = new cfcomponents.mylog(trim(form.username), trim(form.password))>`

Comment: Matt, thanks for letting me know. May I ask what are the benefits with using new instead of the old init() and then cfinvoke? and can you refer me to an article/posting that explain how to use new

Comment: new will call init automatically if it exists, so that's the benefit. If you create the object into a variable you shouldn't be using cfinvoke at all.

Comment: The old init() and then cfinvoke?  That has never been a good idea.  Once an object has been created, you can simply call its methods using the syntax in this answer.  Using cfinvoke would create another instance of the component, which would be inefficient.